# GROUP BY all columns except two date fields and manipulate the date fields in query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that returns a bunch of columns including two date fields: START_DATE and END_DATE. I need to modify the query so that if all fields other than the dates are equal the rows are combined and the START_DATE is changed to the MIN date of all the combined rows and END_DATE is changed to the MAX date of all the combined rows?

Is this possible to do with CASE statements and subqueries?

```
SELECT 
    RA, 
    RA,
    START_DATE,
    END_DATE,
    RA, 
    GT,
    RG, 
    SR,   
    SR, 
    SR, 
FROM  RG,  RA,  SR,  GT
WHERE SR = RG
AND GT = RG
AND RA = 'asdH'
AND RA NOT IN ('G', 'W')
AND RA. = RG.
AND SR. = GT.;
```

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results so you question makes sense.

Comment: TuCraiN, it would be good to add your query too

Comment: I dont think the question is THAT complicated. If all the fields besides the two dates are equal then combine them(GROUP BY) and display the MIN date of one of the dates and the MAX date of the other one

Comment: TuCraiN, yes, it is possible with  with CASE statements and subqueries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer to your question, I dont have a lot of details so, a lot is left to imagination:

```
SELECT 
    RA.field1, 
    RA.field2,
    min(START_DATE) as START_DATE,
    max(END_DATE) as END_DATE,
    RA.field3, 
    GT.field4,
    RG.field5, 
    SR.field6,   
    SR.field7, 
    SR.field8, 
FROM  RG,  RA,  SR,  GT
WHERE SR = RG
AND GT = RG
AND RA = 'asdH'
AND RA NOT IN ('G', 'W')
AND RA. = RG.
AND SR. = GT.
group by 
    RA.field1, 
    RA.field2, 
    RA.field3, 
    GT.field4,
    RG.field5, 
    SR.field6,   
    SR.field7, 
    SR.field8
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. This is literally what I was about to try. I will let you know if it works :)

Comment: This solved it. I have a tendency to over-complicate small issues...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,
min(START_DATE) as START_DATE ,max(END_DATE) as END_DATE
FROM (
SELECT field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,START_DATE,END_DATE FROM RG
UNION
SELECT field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,START_DATE,END_DATE from RA
UNION
SELECT field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,START_DATE,END_DATE FROM SR
UNION
SELECT field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,START_DATE,END_DATE
FROM GT) t
GROUP BY field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8;
```